# 'fetch' call comes back as undefined?

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native, post, fetch

I'm currently working on a react-native app that retrieves data from a php Backend, when I call the following function my compiler keep coming back with a 
"'fetch' is not def"
Does anyone know why I might be getting some error?

```
onButtonPress = () => {  fetch('http://www.fitnessinspirationtechnologies.com/ReactNative/login_RN.php', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
  body: JSON.stringify({
    response: 'response',
    id: 'id',
    type: 'type'
  })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res.response, res.id, res.type);
})
.done();
```

}

Comment: Check this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but even if fetch works, I would use axios, which is much better, especially handling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is front-end only, and in some browsers isn't yet supported. I'm guessing your react native environment doesn't yet support `fetch`.

You could consider adding a polyfill for it, which gives you a server-side version and creates this function for those browsers.

`$ npm install --save unfetch`

Then import it into your project:

`import fetch from 'unfetch'` using ES6

`var fetch = require('unfetch')` using CommonJS modules

Comment: react-native support fetch

Comment: @Revansiddh thanks, indeed - I just read up on that. Perhaps this is running in a test suite which doesn't support it? Unclear from the original post.